# What is the most appropriate camera for hobby photography?

Tags: camera-basics, camera-recommendation

I like to travel and take snaps a lot, I usually use my mobile camera for this, but it is not worthy at all. 
Can someone suggest to me a good and affordable digital camera between the range of $100 - $200 (It is the only amount I can spend currently). I studied a lot on the 'net, but you can't tell how it will perform until you buy it. So, please suggest a good one, which you guys have already used or experienced. Megapixels can be compromised like (5-7 MP will do) but I would really love to have some optical zoom, and point and shoot capability.

Comment: Can't really say that there is a "best" camera for anything. It might be good to reword your title to remove "best" and use a better term, such as "What are the most appropriate cameras for...", and mitigate the subjectivity a bit. This thread should really be a community wiki as well, as there are not really any "correct" answers here, just varying opinions. Barring significant objection, I'll convert this to CW in a few hours.

Comment: Other than labnut's answer, this question now stands as a wonderful example of why shopping questions are a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be more effective to post your question in one of the many camera forums such as [DPReview](http://www.dpreview.com/). They have a large and thriving membership that is very active. They commonly answer questions about camera choices and upgrade paths. You will get many more replies from some very experienced and knowledgeable members.

Since those sites are usually partitioned according to camera make you can pose your questions to the supporters of the different camera makes. In this way, by hearing the opinions of the different supporters, you can form a good overall impression of what will best suit your needs.

The debate about make of camera often inspires a great deal of biased partisanship which is best kept in the relevant forums. Such divisive debates about what is in the end a very subjective issue will harm the objectivity and neutrality of this site and reduce its informative value.

Comment: DP Review also has a great comparison section - http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/sidebyside.asp

Comment: Generally speaking, a comment like this should really go on the Photo.SE meta site, with a comment linking it. This really isn't an ideal "answer" for this site, as it is more a discussion of what is acceptable/not acceptable here. I recommend either finding related threads on meta (there should be some), or starting a new one if none of the existing ones fit, and link it in a comment to the original question.

Comment: @jrista: Yes, what you say makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your budget and requirements, I'd suggest something like the [Canon SD 1400](http://www.digitalcamerareview.com/default.asp?newsID=4289&review=canon+powershot+sd1400).

While it would not be considered a super camera by most serious photographers, I think it may be more than enough for your needs.

I've been using Canon compacts for years and they surely deliver a lot more than expected at first glance. :o)

One thing I like a lot is how simple is to use the P mode on them, where you can have more control over exposure (how much light goes in the picture) and focus (being able to switch from landscape to close ups easily is very important).

But of course your mileage may vary...

Comment: Thanks Andre, Its a nice camera, but i would prefer " Canon PowerShot SD1300 IS" rather than this.. what do you suggest

Comment: The SD 1300 seems to be a good choice (at least according to http://www.image-acquire.com/canon-sd1300-camera-review-beats-the-1400/), I've mentioned the 1400 instead because I had a chance to use it for a few days (but not the 1300).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should go for a model which provides some manual control also, rather than a simple point and shoot. I use Canon S3IS, which is a great camera. Newer models have come in, which you can check.

The advantages of such a camera :

- Provides more control over shots, so that you can experiment. For example, aperture, shutter speed, ISO can all be controlled manually
- Great optical zoom (10X).

Cons :

- Bit bulky

Comment: Thanks Abhinav... Its very nice camera , but sadly it is out of my budget.. costs around 15,000 in india ($340 approx)