# Which camera/lenses should I buy?

Tags: equipment-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I look for when shopping for my first DSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr)

I'm entry level on the photography stuff. Wanting to learn and get a camera. Main focus is taking pictures of my son. Want to start with a decent camera, but not go overboard if I dont have to. I have been looking at the Canon T3i, Nikon 5100, and Nikon D90. Want to have to carry as little lenses as I have to, but want good pictures. Tell me everything you know about these, or if you have any other reccs let me know pleasee.

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13434/d5100-or-d90-which-one-to-buy-as-the-first-dslr

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5641/im-getting-started-in-photography-and-taking-a-photography-class-what-camera

Comment: Have you tried at looking at the various other questions which treat this topic? on the right hand side of the question you will find them, under the Related header.

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/help-me-decide-which-camera-to-buy

Comment: How old is your son?    What will he be doing while you're taking pictures?   Teething?   Playing college basketball?

Answer (score 1):

Pick any of the entry level cameras that fit your budget. Assuming you don't care too much about zooming into far away things, you'll be fine with the kit lens (18-55 in most cases). You might find 18-105 or 18-200 bundled with many cameras, that should be just fine too. Most important thing is for you to get comfortable with using the camera.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should look at Sony cameras. Their DSLRs (really SLTs) are pretty cool. You would have to pay a much greater price for a Nikon or Canon with a similar burst speed (burst mode could be very useful when taking pictures of your son). My biggest complaint with my a55 is the noise at moderate ISO levels - not a deal breaker, though. 
So check out the Sony's. They have reasonable prices, and also have some nice lenses too if you want to spend a little more for some better glass. [www.sonystyle.com](http://sonystyle.com)